# Templated Panel with custom look

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, controls, panel

I'm trying to create an custom Panel with a template. At least trying. I know that Panel doesn't have a template but I need to apply a corner radius, shadow and background on that Panel. I was searching for a solution but I didn't found anything that could help me.

**XAML Code**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SupremeCard}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SupremeCard}">
                <local:ClippingBorder CornerRadius="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <local:ClippingBorder.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" ShadowDepth="1" Direction="270" Color="#CCCCCC" Opacity="1"/>
                    </local:ClippingBorder.Effect>
                    <Grid x:Name="MainContainer"></Grid>
                </local:ClippingBorder>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Current Code**

```
public class SupremeCard : Control
{
    static SupremeCard()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SupremeCard), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SupremeCard)));
    }
}
```

Basically as You can see I have nothing. Have tried to transform SupremeCard into Panel but I can't modify it's look. Has Tried to implement a grid inside SupremeCard (as Control) and Children but after dropping and item inside that "panel" items were disappearing or throwing "Could not create instance of object" exception.

**Code before:**

```
[DesignTimeVisibleAttribute()]
[TemplatePart(Name = "MainContainer", Type = typeof(Grid))]
public class SupremeCard : Control
{
    public ObservableCollection<UIElement> Children { get; private set; }

    private Grid MainContainer { get; set; }

    static SupremeCard()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SupremeCard), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SupremeCard)));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        MainContainer = base.Template.FindName("MainContainer", this) as Grid;
    }

    public SupremeCard()
    {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<UIElement>();

        Children.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Children_CollectionChanged);
    }

    void Children_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (UIElement elem in e.NewItems)
                {
                    MainContainer.Children.Add(elem);
                }

                break;
            case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                break;
            case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:

                foreach (UIElement elem in e.OldItems)
                {
                    MainContainer.Children.Remove(elem);
                }
                break;
            case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                break;
            case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

For same XAML construction. Any help?

Comment: 1. A `Panel` has no look, so I don't understand how you can make your control look like a `Panel`. 2. *Have tried to transform SupremeCard into Panel but I can't modify it's look*... if you just want to extend `Panel`, then just extend `Panel` instead of `Control`: `public class SupremeCard : Panel`

Comment: Tried already. Overrading Arrange and Measure. But I can't modify it's look because it's a panel.

Comment: *I can't modify it's look because it's a panel*... what look??? What are you really trying to do here overall, because your question is very unclear?

Comment: I'm trying to create some kind of group/panel that will hold other elements. This panel should have a white background and a shadow underneath. Something like Google Card from their material design.

Answer (score 1):

`Panel`s in WPF have no look by default. If you want to make a `Panel` have a white `Background`, then you can just set its `Background` property to `White`:

```
<StackPanel Background="White">
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

If you want it to have a shadow, then simply add one:

In Resources:

```
<DropShadowEffect x:Key="Shadow" BlurRadius="10" Direction="270" ShadowDepth="7" 
    Opacity="0.5" />
```

...

```
<StackPanel Background="White" Effect="{StaticResource Shadow}">
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

Please don't make the common mistake of thinking that WPF is like WinForms, as it is very different. We often had to create new controls in WinForms for many reasons, but WPF is not like that at all. In fact, when using WPF, there is very little reason to create new controls, because we can adapt the standard controls using `Style`s and even defining new `ControlTemplate`s.

I think that you could benefit from reading through the [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to see what is possible with WPF.

---

UPDATE >>>

> *I have a problem in setting corner radius (like in border).*

As I keep telling you... `Panel`s have no look by default, so you can just add it into another control to give it a look:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Background="White" 
    Effect="{StaticResource Shadow}">
    <StackPanel>
        ...
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Comment: I know about styling in WPF but I'm creating personal control library for future use. However I know how to set background to white. I have a problem in setting corner radius (like in border). Thanks for comeback.

Comment: Where I can put this? Into which Control. I repeat, I'm trying to create a single control with all this look to apply this easily later.

Comment: How about extending the `Border` class?

Comment: Yes but in designer when I drop the item I should pass it to my Panel. I have tried that with the code above but the problem is that items become invisible or they throw an exception.